# HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode replacement for netstandard

Tags: .net, base64, urlencode, .net-standard

I'm porting a project targeting `net472` to `netstandard`. The last `System.Web` dependency I'm stuck with is [`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Byte[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_UrlTokenEncode_System_Byte___).

I found [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`](https://fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/2.1.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities), which contains [`Base64UrlTextEncoder`](https://fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/2.1.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/Base64UrlTextEncoder) and [`WebEncoders`](https://fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/2.1.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/WebEncoders), but those are not interchangeable with the `UrlTokenEncode`/`Decode`, as it appends / expects the number of [`=` padding characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6916805/155005) at the end, e.g.:

```
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SO");
Convert.ToBase64String(data);              // U08=
HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(data);    // U081 - this is what's expected and 
                                           // the only thing UrlTokenDecode can handle
Base64UrlTextEncoder.Encode(data);         // U08
WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(data);         // U08
```

As far as I can tell, there are no other differences (I ran tests with random strings), but it also pulls in some other dependencies (Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers & Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives), that I don't really need in that project.

Is there any nuget package with a drop-in replacement? I'm thinking of implementing this myself, if not.

Answer (score 33):

For those whom looks for the answer of this removed utility method and wish to migrate legacy application across, I have done some extract from M$ source.

```
   private static string UrlTokenEncode(byte[] input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        if (input.Length < 1)
            return String.Empty;
        char[] base64Chars = null;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 1: Do a Base64 encoding
        string base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
        if (base64Str == null)
            return null;

        int endPos;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 2: Find how many padding chars are present in the end
        for (endPos = base64Str.Length; endPos > 0; endPos--)
        {
            if (base64Str[endPos - 1] != '=') // Found a non-padding char!
            {
                break; // Stop here
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 3: Create char array to store all non-padding chars,
        //      plus a char to indicate how many padding chars are needed
        base64Chars = new char[endPos + 1];
        base64Chars[endPos] = (char)((int)'0' + base64Str.Length - endPos); // Store a char at the end, to indicate how many padding chars are needed

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 3: Copy in the other chars. Transform the "+" to "-", and "/" to "_"
        for (int iter = 0; iter < endPos; iter++)
        {
            char c = base64Str[iter];

            switch (c)
            {
                case '+':
                    base64Chars[iter] = '-';
                    break;

                case '/':
                    base64Chars[iter] = '_';
                    break;

                case '=':
                    Debug.Assert(false);
                    base64Chars[iter] = c;
                    break;

                default:
                    base64Chars[iter] = c;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new string(base64Chars);
    }

    private static byte[] UrlTokenDecode(string input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        int len = input.Length;
        if (len < 1)
            return new byte[0];

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 1: Calculate the number of padding chars to append to this string.
        //         The number of padding chars to append is stored in the last char of the string.
        int numPadChars = (int)input[len - 1] - (int)'0';
        if (numPadChars < 0 || numPadChars > 10)
            return null;


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 2: Create array to store the chars (not including the last char)
        //          and the padding chars
        char[] base64Chars = new char[len - 1 + numPadChars];


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 3: Copy in the chars. Transform the "-" to "+", and "*" to "/"
        for (int iter = 0; iter < len - 1; iter++)
        {
            char c = input[iter];

            switch (c)
            {
                case '-':
                    base64Chars[iter] = '+';
                    break;

                case '_':
                    base64Chars[iter] = '/';
                    break;

                default:
                    base64Chars[iter] = c;
                    break;
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Step 4: Add padding chars
        for (int iter = len - 1; iter < base64Chars.Length; iter++)
        {
            base64Chars[iter] = '=';
        }

        // Do the actual conversion
        return Convert.FromBase64CharArray(base64Chars, 0, base64Chars.Length);
    }
```

Comment: This was tested within our project on 9-25-19 and works as a replacement for:
System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode (str)

Comment: Here's a link to the reference source: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs#L856

Comment: I'm not fan of the idea to add a big class to my project directly ripped from MS sources, but it appeared to be the easiest and safest solution to mimic the exact behavior of UrlTokenEncode/Decode without to have a dependency to System.Web for a legacy assembly used in both .Net 4 and .Net 7 projects (migration in progress). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My KISS, solution, that works on `netstandard1.6`:

```
public static class Utils
{
    private static readonly Regex InvalidBase64UrlTokens = new Regex(
        @"[^=a-z0-9]", 
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    public static string Base64UrlTokenEncode(byte[] data)
    {
        var padding = 0;
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        return InvalidBase64UrlTokens.Replace(base64String, m => {
            switch (m.Value)
            {
                case "+": return "-";
                case "=":
                    padding++;
                    return "";
                default: return "_";
            }
        }) + padding;
    }
}
```

Passes the following nunit tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Base64UrlTokenEncodingTests
{        
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> CompareAgainstSystemWebImplementationCases()
    {
        var random = new Random(42);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[i + 1];
            random.NextBytes(bytes);

            var name = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            var systemWeb = System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes);
            yield return new TestCaseData(bytes).SetName(name).Returns(systemWeb);
        }
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(CompareAgainstSystemWebImplementationCases))]
    public string CompareAgainstSystemWebImplementation(byte[] data) =>
        Utils.Base64UrlTokenEncode(data);
}
```

Comment: This implementation is buggy, it gives a different result than `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncoding` when an equals sign (`=`) is present in the input byte array.

Answer (score 0):

In net core : Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.Base64UrlEndCoder

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders?view=aspnetcore-5.0?

Comment: .Net Core != .Net Standard

Comment: I actually tried that, and it gives slightly different result from HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's MS Original:

```
static string UrlTokenEncode(byte[] input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }
    if (input.Length < 1)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string text = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
    if (text == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int num = text.Length;
    while (num > 0 && text[num - 1] == '=')
    {
        num--;
    }
    char[] array = new char[num + 1];
    array[num] = (char)(48 + text.Length - num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];
        if (c != '+')
        {
            if (c != '/')
            {
                if (c != '=')
                {
                    array[i] = c;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i] = c;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                array[i] = '_';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = '-';
        }
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```