# HttpUtility.UrlEncode in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am migrating from .net framework to .net core.
In my current application I have:

```
private static string ToBase64Url(string value) => ToBase64Url(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));

private static string ToBase64Url(byte[] value)
{
  var s = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(value).ToCharArray();
  return new string(s, 0, s.Length - 1);
}
```

I tried changing that to:

```
private static string ToBase64Url(byte[] value)
{
  var s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value).ToCharArray();
  return new string(s, 0, s.Length - 1);
}
```

However that gives me different results:

test data:

`var text = {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"};`

result in .net framework: `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9`

result in .net core: `%7b%22alg%22%3a%22RS256%22%2c%22typ%22%3a%22JWT%22%7`

what should be the right equivalent here?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731397/httpserverutility-urltokenencode-replacement-for-netstandard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode replacement for netstandard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731397/httpserverutility-urltokenencode-replacement-for-netstandard)

Comment: yes, thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

Using the link above I created shorter version that worked for me:

```
private static string ToBase64Url(byte[] value) =>
            Convert.ToBase64String(value).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').TrimEnd('=');
```