# How to create a string in sql using ef core which will unique in whole system?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq

1. I have one class in c# which contains the referral Property.
   like below

   class Abc {
         public string referral {get;set;}
       }
2. When I will use migration I will be generated as a column in the table (in SQL).
3. I want the value of that filed to be unique in the whole system.
4. And the length should be 20 without any space.

Note: I am adding value from UI to value should be known to me It shouldn't any random string.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Read: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278909/net-short-unique-identifier

Comment: Use an int field and draw its value from a sequence.

Comment: "I want the value of that filed to be unique in the whole system" <= does this means that every table in your DB should have this column filled with some unique but static value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

to generate unique strings and then just store them in Data base and of cause you will need to customize EF migration script

Comment: That's too long

Comment: The size limit is only 20 characters. And I have to add that from UI.

Comment: @BhushanDhage The just do increasing sequence of numbers from 1, 2, 3 to end and convert them to string

Comment: @Serghei auto-increment in client code is a bad idea, and can lead to database concurrency issues.

Comment: Why not just decorate the property with the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Abc {
[Key]
[StringLength(20)]
      public string referral {get;set;}
    }`
```

if you are inputing the string from the ui this will ensure that the string is unique for all your db entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Abc 
{
  [Index(IsUnique = true), Required, MaxLength(20)]
  public string referral {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: And how to set this?

Comment: I don't think it is unique in the whole database. I think unique keyword is table specific.

Answer (score 0):

The way to create unique identifiers in client code is using `System.Guid`, but they are 32 characters long, even with the hyphens removed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9279005/8126362) is a nice way to truncate a GUID, but it still uses 22 characters.

If you need to use something shorter, then your going to increase the risk of collisions, but this gives a 1 in 7 × 10^32 which is probably adequate:

```
string Generate20Characters()
{
    string characters = "abcderfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    return string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 20).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]));
}
```

Comment: @jonhtahn I can not use the random generator as value should be known to me. As I am adding value from UI itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, how should the strings be "known"?

Answer (score 0):

This answer here gives a detailed explanation of creating [short unique strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/how-can-i-generate-random-alphanumeric-strings)

A simplest solution would be to :

```
// Specify characters to incclude in the unqiue Id
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
// Create char array of 20 length which you need
var charArray = new char[20];
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    charArray[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}

var uniqueString = new String(charArray);
```

Another easier and simple approach would have been to Base64 encode a Guid which would result in a 24 character unique string which would end with == which you can trim to further shorten it to 22.

```
var newId = Guid.NewGuid();
var uniqueString = Convert.ToBase64String(newId.ToByteArray());
```

But as your length requirement is 20 you can stick to the first one.

Comment: Random doesn't mean unique.All pseudo-random number generators eventually start producing the same numbers.