# [guid]::NewGuid().GetBytes() returns different result than [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(...)

Tags: powershell, encoding, base64

I found this excellent approach on shortening GUIDs here on stackowerflow:  [.NET Short Unique Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278909/net-short-unique-identifier)

I have some other strings that I wanted to treat the same way, but I found out that in most cases the Base64String is even longer than the original string.

My question is: why does `[guid]::NewGuid().ToByteArray()` return a significant smaller byte array than `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([guid]::NewGuid().Guid)`?

For example, let's look at the following GUID:

```
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$guid

Guid
----
34c2b21e-18c3-46e7-bc76-966ae6aa06bc
```

With `$guid.GetBytes()`, the following is returned:

```
30
178
194
52
195
24
231
70
188
118
150
106
230
170
6
188
```

And `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($guid.ToByteArray())` generates `HrLCNMMY50a8dpZq5qoGvA==`

`[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($guid.Guid))`, however, returns `MzRjMmIyMWUtMThjMy00NmU3LWJjNzYtOTY2YWU2YWEwNmJj`, with `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($guid.Guid)` being:

```
51
52
99
50
98
50
49
101
45
49
56
99
51
45
52
54
101
55
45
98
99
55
54
45
57
54
54
97
101
54
97
97
48
54
98
99
```

Comment: in the second case you're encoding the string representation of the Guid

Answer (score 0):

The [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid) struct is an object storing a 16 byte array that contains its value.
These are the 16 bytes you see when you perform its method `.ToByteArray()` method.

The 'normal' **string** representation is a grouped series of these bytes in hexadecimal format. (4-2-2-2-6)

As for converting to **Base64**, this will always return a longer string because each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data.

Therefore, every three 8-bits bytes of the input (3×8 bits = 24 bits) can be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits (4×6 = 24 bits).
The resulting string can even be extended with `=` padding characters at the end of the string to always be a multiple of 4.
The result is a string of `[math]::Ceiling(<original size> / 3) * 4` length.

Using `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([guid]::NewGuid().Guid)` is actually first performing the GUID's `.ToString()` method and from that **string** it will return the ascii values of each character in there.
(hexadecimal representation = 2 characters per byte = 32 values + the four dashes in it leaves a 36-byte array)

Answer (score 0):

```
[guid]::NewGuid().ToByteArray()
```

In the scope of this question, a GUID can be seen as a 128-bit number (actually it is a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), but that's not relevant to the question). When converting it into a byte array, you divide 128 by 8 (bits per byte) and get an array of **16 bytes**.

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([guid]::NewGuid().Guid)
```

This converts the GUID to a hexadecimal string representation first. Then this string gets encoded as UTF-8.

A hex string uses **two characters per input byte** (one hex digit for the lower and one for the upper 4 bits). So we need at least 32 characters (16 bytes of GUID multiplied by 2). When converted to UTF-8 each character relates to exactly one byte, because all hex digits as well as the dash are in the basic ASCII range which maps 1:1 to UTF-8. So including the dashes we end up with 32 + 4 = **36 bytes**.

So this is what `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String()` has to work with - 16 bytes of input in the first case and 36 bytes in the second case.

Each Base64 output digit represents up to 6 input bits.

- 16 input bytes = 128 bits, divided by 6 = **22** Base64 characters
- 36 input bytes = 288 bits, divided by 6 = **48** Base64 characters

That's how you end up with more than twice the number of Base64 characters when converting a GUID to hex string first.

Comment: Note, too, that MS's GUIDs are more complex than just 128-bit numbers. They're data structures, and Microsoft represents a GUID as 32-bit number, two 16-bit numbers, and eight 8-bit numbers (bytes). For example, given the GUID `34c2b21e-18c3-46e7-bc76-966ae6aa06bc`, when you call `ToByteArray()` you'll get `1e, b2, c2, 34, c3, 18, e7, 46, bc, 76, 96, 6a, e6, aa, 06, bc`.  The first four bytes are reversed (little endian), and the second two, and the third two, but the rest are "in order". Microsoft is consistent with this representation, but it can easily mislead you.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks, I've changed the first sentence to clarify.